# How to prevent a MANIFEST.MF file from being modified?

Tags: java, jar

It seems a MANIFEST.MF file in a jar file can be easily modified with a zip tool. Suppose I add `Sealed: true` in the manifest file to prevent others from using my package-wide types. How can we ensure it is not modified after distribution?

### ADD 1

I just found this link : [JAR files revealed](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jar/).

There's a section about `Security in JAR files`. Maybe that addresses my question.

Comment: Can't they just extract your MANIFEST.MF file with zip, remove the sealed stuff, and put it back with zip?

Comment: You should sign your jar, which will generate .SF (signature file) file which contains sha code calculated from your manifest file.

Comment: @Marichyasana I don't think you get my point.

Comment: No I don't get it, can't someone just change the manifest with a new signature? Or are you encrypting the files?

Comment: I just want to make sure my intention of sealing this package is not jeopardized by someone else. I am thinking about things like signing, and Naruto mentioned that, too. Pardon me if this is a dumb question because I just move to Java platform.